# React-Native Many Unknown Crashes on Crashlytics

Tags: react-native, crashlytics

I've updated an application on the playsotre with new version which been developed with react-native for an application which was already exist with a lot of users.
Since then, every day I see several crashes on crashlytics which have no logs that effects my app's users.

The full error log is:
Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000010
at (Missing)()
at (Missing)()
at (Missing)()

It happens on diffrenect screens on android versions 9 & 10 mostly on new devices.
Im using react-native 0.61.5.
Does anybody encountered this kind of bug?

Tnx

Comment: Can you add a complete screenshot of the stack trace?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tig457

Comment: Do you have another debugger / xcode connected when the app crashes?

Comment: I cant reproduce this crash on my machine. I have 15K daily active users and every day I get 50 crashes like this.